# Remove image by pressing Backspace key

Tags: javascript, html, validation, inputbox

Here, I'm validating the answer in the Input box.i.e. When i types a correct answer appropriate tick image will come likewise for wrong image also.
In that case, when i pressed the backspace key the image needs to be disappear.

My html code is:

```
<div class="arithmetic-rw addition-rw" id="addition1" style="position:absolute; left:330px;top:220px; text-align:center; font-size:30px; font-family:arial;">
    <input id="textvisible1" type="text" value="" style="font-size:27px;text-align:center; padding-top:25px; border:0px; position:absolute; left:0px; height:50px; width:150px;" maxlength="4" onblur="javascript:checktxt('texthidden1','texthidden1a','textvisible1','wrong1','correct1');" />
    <div class="correct1"  style="position:absolute;margin-left: 160px; margin-top: 20px; float:right; display: none; "><img src="../images/smallgreen.png"/></div>
    <div class="wrong1" style="position:absolute;margin-left: 160px; margin-top: 20px; float:right; display: none; "><img src="../images/smallwrong.png"/></div>
    <input id="texthidden1" type="hidden" value="413"/>
    <input id="texthidden1a" type="hidden" value="410"/>
</div>
```

And my JS code is:

```
function remove(ah,aha,av,aw,ac) {
    var ath=$("#"+ah).val();
    var ath1=$("#"+aha).val();
    var atv=$("#"+av).val();
    if(atv.toLowerCase() || ath.toLowerCase()) {
        $( "."+ac ).hide();
        $( "."+aw ).hide(); 
    }
}
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(a){
    if(a.keyCode == 8) {
        remove('texthidden1','texthidden1a','textvisible1','wrong1','correct1')
        remove('texthidden2','texthidden2a','textvisible2','wrong2','correct2')
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you want to do it on backspace? what about if they use the delete key? or highlight text and type over it? would it not be better to just re-validate the answer on the change event for the field?